# Creating SignerPayload for PolkadotJS Extenstion: Unsupported extrinsic payload version 0

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot-js-extension, signing

I am trying to create a `SignerPayloadJSON` from an encoded partial extrinsic in polkadotjs. The partial extrinsic has the following hex representation

```
0x00001448656c6c6f000000c22400001600000081bf2e35e70dbc700b2b3a189a6ced2a3f4d098aaf08dbdd63089bc714de2c2e81bf2e35e70dbc700b2b3a189a6ced2a3f4d098aaf08dbdd63089bc714de2c2e
```

and decodes to the following data when decoded by the polkadot js browser app:

```
callIndex
    0000
remark
    14 48656c6c6f
era
    00 00
nonce
    00
tip
    00
specVersion
    c2240000
transactionVersion
    16000000
genesisHash
    81bf2e35e70dbc700b2b3a189a6ced2a3f4d098aaf08dbdd63089bc714de2c2e
blockHash
    81bf2e35e70dbc700b2b3a189a6ced2a3f4d098aaf08dbdd63089bc714de2c2e
```

We create an api connection to a local node like so:

```
const api = await ApiPromise.create({
    provider: new WsProvider("ws://127.0.0.1:9944"),
  });
await api.isReady;
```

How can we create the `SignerPayloadJSON` object, given that we have access to the ss58 formatted address of the user? We tried to first decode the data into an ExtrinsicPayload like so:

```
let extrinsicPayload = api.createType("ExtrinsicPayload", payload_hex, {
    version: 4,
  });
```

But this `extrinsicPayload` object then has an empty field `method: ""` which seems odd.

I tried to craft this payload manually like so:

```
let hand_crafted_signer_payload = {
    address: "5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY",
    blockHash:
      "0x559440460afd0b06684f4cecced86acdb4a278e0b77fa26b0eb67531523d6f34",
    blockNumber: "0x02",
    era: "0x0000",
    genesisHash:
      "0x81bf2e35e70dbc700b2b3a189a6ced2a3f4d098aaf08dbdd63089bc714de2c2e",
    method: "0x00001448656c6c6f",
    nonce: "0x00",
    specVersion: "0xc2240000",
    tip: "0x00",
    transactionVersion: "0x16000000",
    signedExtensions: [],
    version: 4,
  }
```

But submitting it to the extension to be signed like this:

```
const injector = await dapp.web3FromSource("polkadot-js");
let { signature } = await injector?.signer?.signPayload(hand_crafted_signer_payload);
```

always led to an error by the extension:

[image: Error image]

**TLDR:** How can we create a valid `SignerPayloadJSON` from a hex encoded payload and a given ss58 address, such that we can give it for signing to the `polkadotjs` extension?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer here: Polkadot transfer transaction build and sign
https://gist.github.com/islishude/24c2ea503050bd3b0d17d68676ea297c